# Different model field requirements for superuser vs normal user? django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

Example(not true example):
I want the superusers to have to save on register their username and email.
and the normal users to save username, email, and a number(unique=True).

I wanted to use the user models django has, but I don't see how when the number has to be unique? or rather I originally wanted it to be the primary key, but only for normal users. Do I have to manually make two different user classes along with the permissions, authentication etc.? or is there separate user models for admin/user in django?

---

I tried(as a complete amateur, new to oop and django)... after gave up on using it as primary key, bc AbstractUser is fly.

Tried with onetoonefield, but couldn't make a combined form with UserCreationForm, bc "too many fields error". Also weird to have an important part of the user table be in a different table (or is it?).
something like (not 100% accurate):

```
#in models.py
class AdminUser(AbstractUser):
  username
  email

class NormalUser():
   ontoonefield(AdminUser)
   number(unique=True)

#in forms.py
class NormalUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class meta:
    fields

class onetoonefieldForm(NormalUserForm):
   class meta:
     add_field += (number)
```

tried playing with required_fields, but again... number is unique

tried making two abstractUsers... permissions errors

thought about just making it non-unique and just checking on db insert that it's unique, but that seemed like a risk to the database, when it's vital it's unique.

Thank you for listening:)
Have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to manually make two different user classes along with the permissions, authentication etc.? or is there separate user models for admin/user in django?

Django uses one built in [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) and distinguishes three types of users using the attributes `is_staff` and `is_superuser`.

1. Normal user: `is_staff=False`, `is_superuser=False`
2. Staff user (can access the admin interface): `is_staff=True`
3. Super user (can do everything): `is_superuser=True`

If the default user model does not work for you, you can [extend it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [replace it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Having the user decide their primary key, is not the intended default. The primary key is usually decided by the database, which also handles the uniqueness. If you would like to assign a unique number to each user, such as a customer number, I suppose it is easiest to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) with a user profile.